# cerr and cout unexpected output in c++

Tags: c++

I have defined two classes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <list>
using namespace std;


vector<string> zustand_namen = {"Neuwertig","Gut", "Abgegriffen","Unbrauchbar"};

enum class Zustand{Neuwertig,Gut, Abgegriffen,Unbrauchbar};

class Exemplar{
private:
    int num;
    Zustand zust;
    bool verliehen;
public:
    Exemplar(int num,Zustand zust);
    Exemplar(int num);
    bool verfuegbar() const;
    bool entleihen();
    void retournieren(Zustand z);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Exemplar& ex);
};


class Werk{
private:
    string autor;
    string name;
    int jahr;
    vector<Exemplar> vec;
public:
    Werk(string autor,string name,int jahr);
    void erwerben(int nr, Zustand z);
    bool entleihen();
    void retournieren(int index, Zustand z);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Werk& werk);

};
```

Than I tested my result in the main programm:

```
int main() {
  try {
    Exemplar e{0, Zustand::Unbrauchbar};
    cout << e << '\n';
  }
  catch (runtime_error&) {
    cout << "Error1\n";
  }
  try {
    Exemplar e{1};
    cout << e << '\n';
    cerr << e << '\n';
  }
  catch (runtime_error&) {
    cout << "Error2\n";
  }
  try {
    Exemplar e{1001};
    cout << e << '\n';
  }
  catch (runtime_error&) {
    cout<<"Error3\n";
  }



  return 0;
}
```

And I expected output:

```
Error1
[Auflage: 1, Zustand: neuwertig]
[Auflage: 1, Zustand: neuwertig]
Error3
[Auflage: 2, Zustand: gut]
[Auflage: 2, Zustand: gut]
```

But Instead I got:

```
Error1
[Auflage:1, Zustand:Neuwertig]
Error3
[Auflage:1, Zustand:Neuwertig]
```

Why did it happen? What is the reason of this output(I suppose it should be connected with cerr function and how can I fix it, such that to get first output? Any corrections and explanations would be appreciated

P.S My constructors:

```
Werk::Werk(string autor,string name,int jahr):
    autor{autor},
    name{name},
    jahr{jahr}
    {
        if(autor.size()<1) throw runtime_error("autor is incorrect");
        if(name.size()<1) throw runtime_error("name is incorrect");
        if(jahr<1700 ||jahr >2017) throw runtime_error("jahr is incorrect");
    }


Exemplar::Exemplar(int num,Zustand zust):
    num{num},
    zust{zust},
    verliehen{false}
    {
        if(num <1 || num >1000) throw runtime_error("num is incorrect");
    }



Exemplar::Exemplar(int num):
    num{num},
    zust{Zustand::Neuwertig},
    verliehen{false}
    {
        if(num <1 || num >1000) throw runtime_error("num is incorrect");
    }
```

**output operators:**

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Exemplar& ex){
    if(ex.verliehen == true){
        os << "[" << "Auflage:" << ex.num <<", " << "Zustand:" << zustand_namen[static_cast<int>(ex.zust)] <<", " << "verliehen"<<"]";
    }
        os << "[" << "Auflage:" << ex.num <<", " << "Zustand:" << zustand_namen[static_cast<int>(ex.zust)] << "]";
    return os;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Werk& werk){
    os << "[" << werk.autor << ", " << werk.name << ", " << werk.jahr << "{";
    for(int i = 0; i<werk.vec.size();++i){
        if(i < werk.vec.size()-1){
            os << werk.vec[i] << ", ";
        } else{
            os << werk.vec[i];
        }

    }
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Problem can be in `operator<<` methods. Could you add them?

Comment: I would suggest you learn how to step through your code in a debugger

Comment: @kubawal I added

Comment: `'\n'` does not force a flush of the buffer, a `std::endl` does. But because those are still to different streams, the terminal could interleave them in any way.

Comment: `operator<<()` performs output twice if `ex.verliehen == true` and once otherwise.     That would explain the difference in output from what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I expected output:
>
> ```
> Error1
> [Auflage: 1, Zustand: neuwertig]
> [Auflage: 1, Zustand: neuwertig]
> Error3
> [Auflage: 2, Zustand: gut]
> [Auflage: 2, Zustand: gut]
> ```
>
> But Instead I got:
>
> ```
> Error1
> [Auflage:1, Zustand:Neuwertig]
> Error3
> [Auflage:1, Zustand:Neuwertig]
> ```

---

First difference capital version, `neuwertig` vs `Neuwertig` is because of

```
vector<string> zustand_namen = {"Neuwertig","Gut", "Abgegriffen","Unbrauchbar"};
```

---

Second difference, one output line vs two lines, is because of the output operator

```
    if (ex.verliehen == true) {
        os << "[" << "Auflage:" << ex.num <<", " << "Zustand:" << zustand_namen[static_cast<int>(ex.zust)] <<", " << "verliehen"<<"]";
    }

    os << "[" << "Auflage:" << ex.num <<", " << "Zustand:" << zustand_namen[static_cast<int>(ex.zust)] << "]";
```

When the member `verliehen` is set to true, two lines are printed. If the member is false, only one line is printed. The member `verliehen` is initialized to `false` in the constructor and never changed, so the condition is never true and the first line never printed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But can you please explain, why(second differences) in a bit more details?
Becuase I didn't get it.